# using PHP tags in href mailto:

Tags: php, tags, href, mailto

I am working in a system that allows for custom system-generated emails to be sent to users.

The system has its own tags (such as [[EMP_NAME]] which outputs the employee's name).

I want to use one of these tags within the body of a `<a href="mailto: "` link.

However, the tags ( [[EMP_NAME]] ) have their own html tags embedded in them so when it is run, the result of the mailto link displays:

```
Best regards
<strong>John Smith</strong>
```

I have tried using `<pre >` but this just gets included in the mail as well.

I have also tried declaring `$strname = <pre>[[EMP_NAME]]</pre>` and then including $strname in the link body but with no success.

As this editor is embedded within the software, I'm not sure it's that advanced and I'm probably stretching it as it is - so simplest solution preferred.

Would much appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: strip_tags can help you, but it's better to implement your own macros

Comment: Like this?

`<a href="123@example.net?subject=Subject&body=Sample%20Text%0D%0ABest%20regards,%0D%0A' . <?php> strip_tags([[EMP_NAME]]) ?> . '">link text here</a>`

The output from the above is:

Best regards,
' . <?php> strip_tags(<strong>John Smith</strong>) ?> . '

Sorry - i am new to PHP so you may have to be patient with me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please provide more information. Looks like php is not parsed. Is it a php file? Otherwise looks like you have some problems with ("") signs. 

Also why <?php> and not <?php

Comment: Difficult to tell really - The input box is presented as plain text input and the system will do the relevant coding before sending it. I was experimenting and found that using tags works so just tried to advance it from there. Using `<pre>` definitely works - is there anything i can do using this and a concatenation?

Thanks

Comment: If it's just a input box, it may not accept php code :) Please try some php code inside it. e.g. <?php echo 'text'; ?> (should output 'text', not <?php... ). Html tag <pre> just preserves the format of the it's content. The best way is to find how the extend the system with new tags and create your own.  And please don't name html tag as php tags. It's making harder to understand you

Comment: Thanks (and sorry!). I c&p'd what you wrote and it came out blank unfortunately. I also don't think it will allow me to create my own - as i said, its very basic. <pre> appears to remove all the formatting. I just need to find a way of integrating that into the string.

Comment: simple html will not allow you to change the string. It's just representing your data. Unfortunately if you have only text input box in most cases you have no ability to extend anything without adding some code to the sources. But, as I said before I can't see the whole problem by the provided information. So I can only assume and guess.